# Add an ImageGallery under Article

Tags: image-gallery, schema.org

I have for same Article a ImageGallery. How can I add the gallery to an article by Schmea.org?

What is the best property to declare a gallery to an article?
Gallery is "Thing > CreativeWork > WebPage > CollectionPage > ImageGallery".

Is the property `hasPart` (`CreativeWork`) the best one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ImageGallery`](http://schema.org/ImageGallery) type is for image gallery *pages* (as it inherits from [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage)), not for any kind of image gallery.

So `ImageGallery` doesn’t seem to be a suitable type for image galleries that are part of an `Article`.

There doesn’t seem to be a good alternative to model these for `Article`. A simple way is to use the [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) property for each [`ImageObject`](https://schema.org/ImageObject), but this doesn’t allow you to state something about the whole gallery.